# Hide the caret -Insertion point - input bar- Blinking vertical little bar

Tags: javascript, css

There is something that I don't like in my designs, when I use an image in a div as a button there is always this little blinking vertical bar like if there is text or something to mark, I would like to know if there is a way to hide the caret -the little blinking bar- using css or JavaScript in some classes or ids, something like `#myDiv{ caret: no-caret / NO blinking bar :) }`. I really don't like this bar in my navigation buttons for example.

Comment: do you have caret mode turned on in your browser?

Comment: Would be helpful to see some code, probably just an example that recreates the issue.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please.

Comment: Hi guys, I don't know if “caret” is the name of this little bar. I just want to hide this blinking bar when a div is a button, like you hide a whole div using display:none for example, like make a div clickable using cursor:pointer, I don’t want this bar to appear in some div using something like: littleBar:none; I don’t know if the caret is the technical name so I don't know the css that refers to this little bar, and I don't know if actually it is possible to hide it or not, is it? Thanks for your time and help. Greetings. PS. This bar appears as soon as you click on the button.

Comment: I've seen that this happens just with FF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Firefox make sure 'Always use the cursor keys to navigate within pages' is unchecked.

```
Tools > Options > Advanced > General
```

This is a user defined setting so it is only for a specific browser instance and will only affect your computer.

Comment: Hi @luke2012 you nailed it. Yep uncheking this box this blinking bar disappears. Im kind of dissapointed due that I can't handle this behaviour. Thanks for your time and help man, and of course the same goes to the others. Greetings.